# Docker container to network

Tags: docker

I run docker container `docker run -it --network host ubuntu:latest bash`, but when I start there some server(on port 3000 for example), i can not open it from the main os.

How can I start the container (without describing expose or publish port) for up there some servers on different ports dynamicaly, and i want that ports will be available from the outer. I want to create container once, and keep there all changes, and back there via command `docker start ...`, `docker exec ...`

Comment: Why don't you want to use port publishing? The alternative is using the host network mode.

Comment: Why docker if you want a VM? Containers should be short-lived, thus, you shouldn't be connecting to them to install your applications and keep them running like virtual machines is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Visit this link to your solution

Here's [Docker networking](https://earthly.dev/blog/docker-networking/) in the section **The Host Driver**

You will find the following abstract

> As the name suggests, host drivers use the networking provided by the host machine. And it removes network isolation between the container and the host machine where Docker is running. For example, If you run a container that binds to port 80 and uses host networking, the container’s application is available on port 80 on the host’s IP address. You can use the host network if you don’t want to rely on Docker’s networking but instead rely on the host machine networking.

> One limitation with the host driver is that it doesn’t work on Docker desktop: you need a Linux host to use it. This article focuses on Docker desktop, but I’ll show you the commands required to work with the Linux host.

> The following command will start an Ubuntu image and listen to port 80 on the host machine:

```
docker run -it --network host ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

[image]